# Update grep on Ubuntu through apt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

Say, I currently have grep version 2.2 on my system and I would like to upgrade to version >= 2.5.

Other than installing grep through source code, is there a method to update grep using Ubuntu (apt) package manager?

Comment: You already have a version greater than 2.5!

Comment: 21 > 5 :} ...  nothing to update.

Comment: Darn. That's a typo. Sorry about that. Will update it. In any case, my question is just basically "Is there a way to update grep through apt"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even the latest distribution of Ubuntu (16.04 LTS) runs grep version 2.24.
If you want to run a 2.5 version, pull down the deb package and install locally, i.e.

```
cd /tmp
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/40224290/grep_2.5.4-4build1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i ./grep_2.5.4-4build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

...now you have access to fun stuff like `--exclude-dir` ;)

Comment: `--exclude-dir` is exactly what I was after :) For those wondering, here's the source of that launchpadlibrarian link: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/grep/2.5.4-4build1

Answer (score 1):

Your upstream distribution (in this case Ubuntu) provides and supports a particular set of packages.  It would be much more advantageous to upgrade your whole distribution to get a newer version of grep (or really any other package.)

The way to do it, if you choose to go this route, is to create your own .deb package with the newer version.  Place that package in your repo, enable your repo on the system.  Then you can install that deb with apt.

Comment: I am not sure your answer is clear to everyone. It seems like you discourage what OP thought of, encouraged the whole distribution and suggested a way which involves creating own .deb file. Especially "the way to do it" is kind of confusing.
I would humbly suggest re-wording the answer to be more clear.